# Placing part of a string between brackets

Tags: mysql, replace, forum

I am having trouble with replacing something in a column.
I have the "posts" table with the "post_text" column (MediumText).

I want to replace "**EXAMPLE:**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ICaPQLTlguM" with [block]ICaPQLTlguM[/block].

I'm Blocked at the following SQL

```
UPDATE post SET post_text= REPLACE('post_text','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','[block]');
```

How can i incapsulate the video referrence id in the [block][/block] brakets ?

Answer (score 1):

This is more complicated than a simple replace.  Perhaps you want this:

```
UPDATE post
    SET post_text = CONCAT('[block]',
                           substring_index(post_text, '=', -1),
                           '[/block]'
                          );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`concat`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
UPDATE post 
SET post_text=
CONCAT(
  REPLACE(post_text,'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','[block]')
  ,'[/block]'
);
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b928e/1)

Comment: this one's almost there, but the baddest issue here is the fact that in the same table i have other things, Entry Example " HA guys, look at this cool car video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ICaPQLTlguM it's really cool" and i need just the link replaced, it's a total headache